# Change value of span tag onchange event jquery

Tags: jquery, events, onchange, html

I am trying to change the value of span when the user selects an option from the dropdown but this doesn't seem to be working.

HTML:

```
<tr>
                    <td class="field" colspan="4">
                    <select id="mmt">
                    <option value="Metric" selected>METRIC</option>
                    <option value="English">ENGLISH</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="head"><label for="abc">ABC</label></td>
                    <td class="field"><input type="text" id="abc"/><span class="m">MM</span> OD</td>
                    <td class="head"><label for="pqr"></label></td>
                    <td class="field"><input type="text" id="pqr" /><span class="ms">MM</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="head"><label for="xyz">XYZ</label></td>
                    <td class="field"><input type="text"  id="xyz" /></td>
                    <td class="head"><label for="stu"></label></td>
                    <td class="field"><input type="text" id="stu"/><span class="ms">MM</span></td>
                </tr>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {          
                    $('#mmt').change(function() {
                        if ($('#mmt option:selected').text() == "English") {
                            $('.ms').text("INCH");
                        }
                        else {
                            $('.ms').text("MM")     
                        }

                    });

        });
```

Comment: Any JavaScript errors in your error console? Have you tried it at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and clicked on the 'JS Lint' button to see if it reports anything? Could you post [a representative demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: -1 "doesn't seem to be working" is one of the worst description of your problem you can give. https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa "doesn't seem to be working" means nothing is happening. no errors, nothing. it just doesn't work. I'm not sure how else I should describe it.

Comment: @input "doesn't seem to be working" !== "nothing is happening".  The latter is much more descriptive.

Comment: @XyanEwing, okay thanks for the heads up. I'll keep in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#mmt option:selected').text()` will either return `"METRIC"` or `"ENGLISH"`, but never `"English"`.

You want the *value* of the `select` element, not the text content of the selected `option`.
For that use [`$('#mmt').val()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/val/), or simply `$(this).val()`, since `this` refers to the `select` element.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zg6JB/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and pointing out where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your jquery here is solution;

```
$(function() {          
           $('#mmt').change(function() {

           if ($('#mmt option:selected').val() =="English") {
               $('.ms').text("INCH");

               }
           else {
               $('.ms').text("MM")     
           }

          });

        });
```

You can check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SX7n3/71/)